# File is not writing mySQL backup CRON

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to make a MySQL database backup and save the `.sql` file. the utility seems to process just fine but when writing the file. nothing happens. not sure what is wrong? path or code

```
public function mysql_backup()
{

// Load the DB utility class
$this->load->dbutil();

$date = new DateTime();
$time = $date->format('Y-m-d_H-i-s');

// Backup your entire database and assign it to a variable
$prefs = array(
                'tables'      => array(),  // Array of tables to backup.
                'ignore'      => array(),           // List of tables to omit from the backup
                'format'      => 'txt',             // gzip, zip, txt
                'filename'    => 'sql_backup_'.$time.'.sql',    // File name - NEEDED ONLY WITH ZIP FILES
                'add_drop'    => TRUE,              // Whether to add DROP TABLE statements to backup file
                'add_insert'  => TRUE,              // Whether to add INSERT data to backup file
                'newline'     => "\n"               // Newline character used in backup file
              );

$backup = $this->dbutil->backup($prefs); 

// Load the file helper and write the file to your server
write_file('./backup/sql_backup_'.$time.'.sql', $backup);

    echo '<h2>Cron Successfully Runned.</h2>'; 

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me like you didn't load the `file` helper.
Try to add `$this->load->helper('file');` before the code

```
public function mysql_backup()
{

// Load the DB utility class
$this->load->helper('file');
$this->load->dbutil();

$date = new DateTime();
$time = $date->format('Y-m-d_H-i-s');

// Backup your entire database and assign it to a variable
$prefs = array(
                'tables'      => array(),  // Array of tables to backup.
                'ignore'      => array(),           // List of tables to omit from the backup
                'format'      => 'txt',             // gzip, zip, txt
                'filename'    => 'sql_backup_'.$time.'.sql',    // File name - NEEDED ONLY WITH ZIP FILES
                'add_drop'    => TRUE,              // Whether to add DROP TABLE statements to backup file
                'add_insert'  => TRUE,              // Whether to add INSERT data to backup file
                'newline'     => "\n"               // Newline character used in backup file
              );

$backup = $this->dbutil->backup($prefs); 

// Load the file helper and write the file to your server
write_file('./backup/sql_backup_'.$time.'.sql', $backup);

    echo '<h2>Cron Successfully Runned.</h2>'; 

    }
```